# jQuery Mobile - Prevent page navigation after changepage event is triggered

Tags: jquery-mobile

Basically the use case is this:

I have a form that the user is filling out a form and accidentally click another link.  In the pagebeforehide event, I want to stop the navigation.  I tried to do

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
```

but neither of them stop the navigation from happening.  Does anyone have any idea how to do this?  It's not immediately clear how to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.preventDefault();` should work if all your code is in the right places.  Here is a simple example:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
     <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>  
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <label for="text-basic">Type 1 to allow navigation:</label>
        <input type="text" name="text-basic" id="text-basic" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        <a class="ui-btn" href="#page2">Go to page 2</a>
    </div> 
     <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
         <h1>My page footer</h1>
    </div> 
</div>  

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
     <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <h1>My page 2</h1> 
    </div>  
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        page 2
        <a class="ui-btn" href="#page1">Go back to page 1</a>
    </div> 
     <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
         <h1>My page footer</h1>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I have 2 pages and only want the user to go to page 2 if he/she types "1" into the text box.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){

    $( "body" ).on( "pagecontainerbeforetransition", function( event, ui ) {
        var currPage = $( "body" ).pagecontainer( "getActivePage" ).prop("id");
        if (currPage == "page1"){
            var val = $("#text-basic").val();
            if (val != "1") {
                alert("you must enter 1 in the text box!");
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                 $("#text-basic").val("");   
            }
        }
    });

});
```

In the pagecontainer widget pagecontainerbeforetransition event, I see which page we are currently looking at, if it is page1, then check what the user has entered in the textbox. If I do not find the string "1", prevent navigation and alert the user.

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3f3fjjgq/)**

Comment: I saw this example, but it didn't seem to be working for me.  But then again, I haven't converted my structure to the new pagecontainer widget.  Let me try to do that and see if it works.